# Is there any Double Array Trie like data structure that compresses the value instead of the key

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, information-retrieval, trie

Use the index to get the compressed string value.

Like reverse lookup in marisa-trie is to restore a key from its ID.

https://github.com/s-yata/marisa-trie

Comment: what's the motivation? do u wanna save space? if not, then what's wrong in storing the compressed values in a separate container and just store the object pointers as the trie elements?